# Sharepoint Designer 2013: Can't delete custom action

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have sp site upgraded from sp 2010 to 2013.

I built a workflow and added a quick step to the ribbon menu, but now I want to removed the quick step, when I select the name of the custom action and go to delete in sp designer, the "Delete: button is disabled.

Anyone has any idea?

Is there any powershell scripts allow me do the same thing?

Answer (score 6):

There is no delete icon.

Select the quick step/custom action in designer, and use the delete button on your keyboard.

The Custom Actions button is on the bottom-right of the list settings page in designer.